# Factoring scalar multiples out of an associated matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation $T:I\!R^3 \rightarrow I\!R^3$ whose associated matrix is:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{13}{14} &\frac{-2}{14} &\frac{-3}{14}\\\frac{-2}{14} &\frac{10}{14} &\frac{-6}{14}\\\frac{-3}{14}&\frac{-6}{14}&\frac{5}{14}\end{bmatrix}$$

Since all elements share a factor of $\frac{1}{14}$ would writing the associated matrix as

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}13 &-2 &-3\\-2 &10 &-6\\-3&-6&5\end{bmatrix}$$

represent the same linear transformation or would this be a separate linear transformation? If I'm not mistaken, both of these linear transformations share the same kernel and image which would imply that we could say these are equivalent but I'm not sure if that is valid reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, these transformations are not equal. If you denote the second one by $B$, you have $B = 14A$. But yes, they have the same kernel and image. Similarly, if $v$ is a vector and $w = 2v$, then $v$ and $w$ are clearly not equal -- although they share many properties. Does that answer your question in any way?

Comment: Yes. I was just attempting to find the kernel and image of the first matrix and  found it interesting that I could "simplify" it and still find the same results so I just wanted to verify that these were technically not equivalent. Thank you.

Comment: Just a remark: A priori, only statements can be equivalent. Equivalence of objects has to be defined.